# how do I do this? my function doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a 4-in-a-row game using js and HTML and want to implement the "gravity" feature, I've wrote this little function for that but somehow, it outputs a lower output every time I run it:

```js
function gravity(x, z) {
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        if (data[x][i] == 0) {
            y = i
        }        
    }
    setTile(x, y, z)
}
```

How it works: I give it the X-coordinate of the tile and searches for the lowest tile on the grid with that x and sends the x, y, and z(not z-dimension, color the tile needs to be) to the function which plots it on the grid.

Tiny details:

- the lower you go on the grid, the higher the y
- I have jquery installed but used no functions of it

my issue is: every time I run the function, it gives a y of 1 lower with another x and just counts down, which x it may be.

I know this is a long question and maybe language isn't so good, but pls help

Comment: If you only want the lowest matching tile, you have to break out of the loop when you find a match.

Comment: Please add *all* the relevant code so that we can replicate your issue.

Comment: You should declare `y` as a local variable.

Comment: Can you share an example input with expected and actual output? See [mcve].

Comment: A minor comment, please consider passing in `data` to the function instead of it being a global value, that way you can avoid corrupting your array

Comment: @AGE How would that avoid corrupting it? Passing it as a parameter doesn't make a copy.

Comment: Each time you run it, you fill in that tile. So the next time you run it, the unfilled tile will be the next lower one, unless something else clears the tile.

Comment: @Barmar I would ensure that the modified value of `data` is returned, this allows the function to be tested for both correctness and completeness against a set of values i.e. unit testing it

Comment: @AGE Unless you add additional code to make a deep copy, it won't. And only the most ardent functional programming advocates would do that for a singleton structure like the game grid.

Comment: @Barmar going by your suggestion you think that the code is written in an object oriented or functional programming way, I simply made a minor comment to help the person who asked the question, my comment is not harmful nor ardent in any way

Comment: @AGE It's a good idea to pass `data` as a parameter, but not for the reason you give.

Comment: @Barmar you can go either ways, I made one comment towards one means of implementing a more testable function but you seem to lean towards the other way (which I do not disagree with), so can you please instead provide the person who asked the question with your suggestion instead of attacking the one I suggested, which is by the way **another** way of achieving the same thing?